# Sort a list of dict according to an order of another list

Tags: python

I have a list and another list which consists of dictionaries.

```
list1 = ['d', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'g']
list2 = [{'key1':'a', 'key2': 'asdf'}, {'key1': 'f', 'key2': 'dd'}, {'key1': 'b', 'key2': 'afd'}, {'key1': 'c', 'key2': 'ff'}, {'key1': 'd', 'key2': 'aa'}, {'key1': 'e', 'key2': 'aab'}]
```

Neither list1 nor list2 is sorted.

I want to sort list2 so that the order of 'key1' in list2 is the same as it appears in list1.

Some of the elements in list1 may not be contained in key1 of list2.
Similarly, some elements of the list2 may not be in list1.

The desired result is

```
 [{'key1': 'd', 'key2': 'aa'}, {'key1':'a', 'key2': 'asdf'}, {'key1': 'c', 'key2': 'ff'}, {'key1': 'b', 'key2': 'afd'}, , , {'key1': 'e', 'key2': 'aab'}]
```

The common elements of the list1 and key1's of the list2 are 'd', 'a', 'c', 'b', and 'e' as it appears in the list1.
So I picked the elements of list2 which the key1 is the above element in the same order it appears in the list1.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired result doesn't include the dict with `'key1': 'f'`, so I assume you want to filter anything out that can't be sorted according to the rule you've specified.  Start there:

```
>>> list1 = ['d', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'g']
>>> list2 = [{'key1':'a', 'key2': 'asdf'}, {'key1': 'f', 'key2': 'dd'}, {'key1': 'b', 'key2': 'afd'}, {'key1': 'c', 'key2': 'ff'}, {'key1': 'd', 'key2': 'aa'}, {'key1': 'e', 'key2': 'aab'}]
>>> [d for d in list2 if d['key1'] in list1]
[{'key1': 'a', 'key2': 'asdf'}, {'key1': 'b', 'key2': 'afd'}, {'key1': 'c', 'key2': 'ff'}, {'key1': 'd', 'key2': 'aa'}, {'key1': 'e', 'key2': 'aab'}]
```

and then it's a simple matter to sort that based on the `index` of the `key1` in `list1`:

```
>>> sorted((d for d in list2 if d['key1'] in list1), key=lambda d: list1.index(d['key1']))
[{'key1': 'd', 'key2': 'aa'}, {'key1': 'a', 'key2': 'asdf'}, {'key1': 'c', 'key2': 'ff'}, {'key1': 'b', 'key2': 'afd'}, {'key1': 'e', 'key2': 'aab'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `sorted`, which would cost *O(n log n)* in average time complexity, you can achieve the desired result in linear time complexity by building a dict that maps each key in `list1` to its order index, building a new dict from `list2` with order indices mapped from the value of `key1`, and then outputting the values of the new dict in the index order:

```
order = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(list1)}
ordered = {order.get(record['key1']): record for record in list2}
print([ordered[i] for i in range(len(order)) if i in ordered])
```

This outputs:

```
[{'key1': 'd', 'key2': 'aa'}, {'key1': 'a', 'key2': 'asdf'}, {'key1': 'c', 'key2': 'ff'}, {'key1': 'b', 'key2': 'afd'}, {'key1': 'e', 'key2': 'aab'}]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/SimpleNecessaryClosedsource